# Sugestões de comandos no VSCode

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

Estou programando em react-native utilizando o Visual Studio Code, nas extensões instalei

- ESLint
- JavaScript (ES6) code snippets
- jsx
- React Native tools
- React-Native/React/Redux snippets for es6/es7
- Reactjs code snippets

Porém nenhum deles fez oq eu quero, que é dar sugestões de comandos como os de formatação de estilos (fontWeight, backgroundColor) e as opções, ou as principais, esse tipo de coisa.

Tipo transformar em uma ide mesmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vc também pode criar seus próprios snippets

Vai em <kbd>File > Preferences > User Snippets</kbd> no prompt que abrir vc escolhe `JavaScript` por exemplo e cria seus binds.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olha o exemplo abaixo: (nesse caso o **"bgc"** é o atalho para inserir o texto )

```
"Cor do Background": {
    "prefix": "bgc",
    "body": [
        "backgroundColor"
    ],
    "description": "colocar cor no background"
}
```

Outro exemplo:

```
"Estilo de fontWeight": {
    "prefix": "ftw",
    "body": [
        "fontWeight"
    ],
    "description": "colocar estilo de Font Weight"
}
```

No modelo acima o atalho **"ftw"** dispara o texto `fontWeight` completo.

> Vc pode criar inclusive snippets para templates inteiros, depois da uma lida na documentação oficial

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Existe um plugin que faz com que seu VSCode utilize as mesmas teclas de atalho do Eclipse, pode ser uma solução.
O nome do plugin é: Eclipse Keymap.

Comment: Vou dar +1 pois gostei muito do plugin, porém não é o que preciso, ele modifica os atalhos mas não anexa sugestões

Answer (score 2):

Para autocompletar parâmetros e valores em CSS você pode utilizar a extensão [IntelliSense for CSS Class Names](https://github.com/Zignd/HTML-CSS-Class-Completion) que fornece autocompletar para o nome da classe CSS para o atributo da classe HTML com base nos arquivos CSS em seu espaço de trabalho e também suporta o atributo `className` do React (o que talvez também resolva seu problema).