# Como criar um projeto mvc no visual studio code

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, mvc, visual-studio-code

Estou começando aprender a desenvolver para web com c# no visual studio code.
Estou tentando criar um projeto web, o problema é que o comando que estou usando "dotnet new MVC -o NomePasta " já cria uma estrutura.

- Como faço para criar um projeto vazio mvc no visual studio code?

Comment: Você quer criar um projeto MVC vazio ou uma Solution vazia sem nenhum projeto dentro?

Comment: Desculpe, estou aprendendo, tem alugam entre os dois projeto.

Comment: As vezes isso pode te ajudar! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232044/sugest%C3%B5es-de-comandos-no-vscode/265191#265191

Comment: Ps.: Quando você menciona ao Visual Studio Core, seria apenas uma confusão com o Framework DotNet Core ou estaria se referindo ao Visual Studio Code?

Comment: VSCode certo? E não Core, corrige aí seu post! :) abs.

Comment: Estou me referindo o Visual studio code, porque  estou usando o sistema operacional linux.

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta

Comment: @AntonioLima, Veja o início da minha resposta atualizada.

Comment: Obrigado Leandro Angelo, a explicação esta igual a alguns site que foi pesquisado, nas não bem resumida igual a sua, obrigado ajudou muito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para adicionar um projeto ASP.Net Core vazio, você deve abrir um prompt de comando, navegar até o diretório onde deseja criá-la e executar o seguinte comando:

```
dotnet new web
```

O template do MVC já inclui a estrutura inicial desse tipo de projeto, você consultar todos os templates disponíveis através do comando ([referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x)):

```
dotnet new -l
```

Os passos seguintes são para outras versões do Visual Studio, uma vez que o Visual Code não trabalha com padrão de solutions, apenas diretórios.

Para criar uma Solution vazia via Dotnet CLI, você deve abrir um prompt de comando, navegar até o diretório onde deseja criá-la e executar o seguinte comando:

```
dotnet new sln
```

Esse comando não possui nenhum argumento e irá criar um arquivo .sln com o mesmo nome do diretório onde o foi executado.

Agora para adicionar projetos à sua solution você pode utilizar os comandos sln ([referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln)) ou seguir pelo caminho mais prático que criá-los pelo visual studio.

O mesmo pode ser feito dentro do próprio visual studio acessando o menu:

`File -> New Project -> Other Project Types`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para adicionar um projeto web vazio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]