# VisualCode - Suggestion

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Estou iniciando um projeto utilizando JavaScript, no qual o *suggestion* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) não está funcionando completamente.

Ao colocar "." ou a apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> ele só mostra uma única opção (de forma resumida) e não vejo as demais propriedades que um objeto ou vetor pode ter. Parece que mostra de forma resumida.

Como configurar para mostrar todas opções de propriedades ao apertar a tecla?

Configuração do VSCode (setting.json)

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
```

Comment: isso ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232044/sugest%c3%b5es-de-comandos-no-vscode

Answer (score 0):

Acesse a aba de plugins dentro do VSCode e procure por IntelliSense, esse varia de linguagem para linguagem... existem uns para `PHP`, `Unity`, `JS`, `C#` (E outros).

Tente procurar um de seu agrado, abra a configuração dos plugins estilo IntelliSense e lá você pode escolher a quantidade de resultados que o VS mostra!

Lembrando que [aqui](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) você pode baixar plugins para as linguagens que você for usar, isso ajuda o VS a reconhecer os codigos e snippets dessa linguagem.

Tente procurar por VS Code IntelliSense.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]